# Set environmental variable in VS12 C#

Tags: c#, dll, environment-variables

I want to apply the following fix:
[click me](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opm-abort-initializing-libguide40dll)
but I don't find how or where to set this. all I found is [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958185/environmental-variable-in-a-c-sharp) with the command, but when I enter this in cmd it doesn't work..

Isn't there a simple file where I could edit this variable? Or a way to do it in the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically change an Environment variable from within your application, you can use one of the following three commands:

Setting the environment variable for only the current process:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("<VarName>", "<VarValue>", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Setting the environment variable for the current user:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("<VarName>", "<VarValue>", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

Setting the environment variable for the entire system:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("<VarName>", "<VarValue>", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Additional information on [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) with examples.

Comment: Depends on where you need it. If you are manually loading the DLL, put it in just before the first load of it, otherwise put the code into the loading of your application to ensure that it is available whenever the DLL might be called

Comment: I tried to place it in the static void Main() function of the program at the beginning, but it didn't fix the problem I had..

Comment: ok, found the error.. I wrote <TRUE> instead of TRUE etc..
thank you :)